# Nexus 4 won't upgrade to Lollipop

Tags: updates, nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop

Bought a factory refurbished Nexus 4 today. It started with jellybean on the first boot, a few updates later it gets to 4.4.4. Now it tells me that my system is up to date. I have another Nexus 4 running Lollipop 5.0.1. I am on T-Mobile if that maters.

Comment: It's pushed out in waves and with 5.0.2 out now, you may not get it for another while. See https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/f1EOEtihDxI%5B1-25-false%5D for more information

Comment: @NiallC. I thought it rolled out by carrier/area so I thought if one Nexus 4 on my carrier in my area had it all of them did. I didn't even realize it was still rolling out. I've had Lollipop on my other nexus 4 for a couple months I believe.

Comment: Have to admit, I observed the Lollipop OTA is kinda... chaotic, for reasons Google only knows. I suggest you to wait around 1 month. Meanwhile, since it's possible that the update is controlled by the carrier, you might want to contact T-Mobile customer service regarding the OTA. (Sorry, we're not their customer service)

Answer (score -1):

Not matter. But not a sw upgrade uploaded on nexus user center for nexus 4. All u can do that is wait for sw release

Comment: The 5.0 update was released, though. The factory images are [right here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#occam). What is this "nexus user center" you're talking about?